# Unity C# Custom class in dictionaries

Tags: c#, dictionary

So yeah, i feel really dumb to ask this question, but i'm currently in the process of writing a simple pathfinder script. I want to use dictionaries like

`Dictionary<Floor, FloorInfo>`

where floor is the floor tile i am referencing and FloorInfo is custom class as follows:

```
public class FloorInfo
{
     Floor lastFloor;
     float floorValue;

     public FloorInfo(Floor lastF, float val)
     {
         lastFloor = lastF;
         floorValue = val;
     } }
```

But after i create something like

```
FloorInfo info = new FloorInfo(current, F);
```

I cannot get the values, like `info.val` or `info.lastF`

Could you explain to me what am I doing wrong? I feel really awkward that i got stuck on something like that or past 45 minutes.

EDIT: Okay, thank you everyone who already answered. Seems like most obvious things can be quite problematic as well. Thanks again and have a nice day!

Comment: You haven't specify any _access modifier_ (`private/protected/public`) so by default those properties are `private`, i.e. inaccessible from outside of a class.

Answer (score 1):

Make them public if you want to access them from outside the class.

Answer (score 1):

That is because C# class' field's access modifier (by default) is `private`. What you do above is trying to access `private` field outside of the scope of the `class` (which is not allowed).

To access the fields, make its access modifiers `public`, then you can access them outside of the `class` scope:

```
public class FloorInfo
{
     public Floor lastFloor; //note the public keyword
     public float floorValue;

     public FloorInfo(Floor lastF, float val)
     {
         lastFloor = lastF;
         floorValue = val;
     } 
}
```

And simply access the fields like:

```
FloorInfo info = new FloorInfo(current, F);
info.lastFloor = new Floor();
info.floorValue = 45.0;
```

Note that you do not access the `lastF` and `val` from above since they are simply your constructor's parameters. You access the fields of your class, not its constructor's parameters.

That being said, it is more common to access them as `property` rather than `field`.

```
public Floor lastFloor { get; set; }
public float floorValue { get; set; }
```

This is because with `property`, you could set something else in your `getter` and `setter` (such as checking if the inputs for your property is valid), which is, most of the time, a safer design:

```
const float floorValueLimit = 20.0;
private float pFloorValue;
public float floorValue { 
  get { return pFloorValue; }
  set {
    if (value <= floorValueLimit){ //check limit
       pFloorValue = value;
    } //else, don't update
  }
}
```

But you cannot do this using field.

Also, as an additional side note, `public` field would normally have capital letter as its first character in C# typical naming convention:

```
public class FloorInfo
{
     public Floor LastFloor; //note the public keyword
     public float FloorValue;

     public FloorInfo(Floor lastF, float val)
     {
         lastFloor = lastF;
         floorValue = val;
     } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `lastF` and `val` are parameters to your constructor. These are gone as soon as the constructor completes.

You have copied these values to lastFloor and floorValue but currently they are private. You should make these public. If you dont specify a modifier then by default it is private and is not visible outside of the class that they are defined.

```
public class FloorInfo
{
     public Floor lastFloor;
     public float floorValue;

     public FloorInfo(Floor lastF, float val)
     {
         lastFloor = lastF;
         floorValue = val;
     } 
}
```

so you can then reference `info.floorValue` and `info.LastFloor`

If you want good design then you should make these into properties and possibly make the `set` private so they it cannot be changed outside of the FloorInfo class. Also make the properties start with capital letters.

```
public class FloorInfo
{
     public Floor LastFloor { get; private set; }
     public float FloorValue { get; private set; }

     public FloorInfo(Floor lastF, float val)
     {
         lastFloor = lastF;
         floorValue = val;
     } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must mark the fields `lastFloot` and `floorValue` as public, or better yet provide a public property for accessing those private fields, like this:

```
public class FloorInfo
{
     private Floor m_lastFloor;
     private float m_floorValue;

     public Floor LastFloor {
          get { return m_lastFloor; }
     }

     public float FloorValue {
          get { return m_floorValue }
     }

     public FloorInfo(Floor lastF, float val)
     {
         m_lastFloor = lastF;
         m_floorValue = val;
     }
}
```

Then you can access the values like this:

```
FloorInfo info = new FloorInfo(current, F);
float value = info.FloorValue;
```

Comment: Terser (and, IMHO more readable) construction is `public Floor LastFloor {get; private set;}`